# How to show the data coming through intent in the result screen in android?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have listview in screen A once the user clicks on the one of the item in the list it navigates to the next screen where he can see more details of that item which is selected.

User can modify that item in the screen B. One the changes are done once the user come back to screen A that list has to be updated how to do it.

The list I used is a static one.

Code I used are:

```
ArrayList<ItemDetails> image_details = GetSearchResults();

    final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV_main);
    lv1.setAdapter(new ItemListBaseAdapter(this, image_details));

    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) { 
            Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
            ItemDetails obj_itemDetails = (ItemDetails)o;
            Intent i = new Intent(DemoPastSubstitutions.this,DemoPastSubstitutionsDetail.class);
            i.putExtra("substitutesName", obj_itemDetails.getName());
            i.putExtra("positionCompany", obj_itemDetails.getDesignation());
            i.putExtra("phone", obj_itemDetails.getphone());
            i.putExtra("email", obj_itemDetails.getEmail());
            i.putExtra("Date", obj_itemDetails.getDates());
            i.putExtra("imageNo", obj_itemDetails.getImageNumber());
            startActivity(i);
                }  
    });
}
private ArrayList<ItemDetails> GetSearchResults(){
    ArrayList<ItemDetails> results = new ArrayList<ItemDetails>();
    ItemDetails item_details = new ItemDetails();

        item_details.setName("Diesel Dean");
        item_details.setDates("From 02/19/2013 - 04/03/2013");
        item_details.setDesignation("Manager");
        item_details.setphone("+9164589022");
        item_details.setEmail("diesel.dean@sap.com");
        item_details.setImageNumber(1);

        item_details = new ItemDetails();
        item_details.setName("Kate Hudson");
        item_details.setDates("From 01/23/2013 - 02/15/2013");
        item_details.setDesignation("Manager");
        item_details.setphone("+916458902");
        item_details.setEmail("kate.hudson@sap.com");
        item_details.setImageNumber(2);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new ItemDetails();
        item_details.setName("Kevin James");
        item_details.setDates("From 01/01/2013 - 01/02/2013");
        item_details.setDesignation("Manager");
        item_details.setphone("+9164589023");
        item_details.setEmail("kevin.james@sap.com");
        item_details.setImageNumber(3);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new ItemDetails();
        item_details.setName("Gray Cruz");
        item_details.setDates("From 01/10/2013 - 01/20/2013");
        item_details.setDesignation("Manager");
        item_details.setphone("+9164589025");
        item_details.setEmail("gray.cruz@sap.com");
        item_details.setImageNumber(4);
        results.add(item_details);
            return results;
}
```

Base adapter code:
    private static ArrayList itemDetailsrrayList;

```
private Integer[] imgid = {
        R.drawable.p1,
        R.drawable.bb2,
        R.drawable.p2,
        R.drawable.bb5,
        R.drawable.bb6,
        R.drawable.d1
        };

private LayoutInflater l_Inflater;

public ItemListBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ItemDetails> results) {
    itemDetailsrrayList = results;
    l_Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public int getCount() {
    return itemDetailsrrayList.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return itemDetailsrrayList.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = l_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_details_view, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txt_itemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.txt_itemDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemDescription);
        //holder.txt_itemPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        holder.itemImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txt_itemName.setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getName());
    holder.txt_itemDescription.setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getDates());
    holder.itemImage.setImageResource(imgid[itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getImageNumber() - 1]);


    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txt_itemName;
    TextView txt_itemDescription;
    //TextView txt_itemPrice;
    ImageView itemImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use startActivityForResult() instead of startActivity() and override onActivityResult() in Screen A
- Pass item index along with the other data to Screen B
- Once modified in Screen B - Send all the data back along with the index, back to Screen A via a Bundle (use setResult() before finishing the Activity in Screen B).
- Once you finish Screen B, you'd get a call back in onActivityResult(), where you can extract the data and update your list.
- After updating the data in your list, don't forget to call ListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
- Please note, Since you use static list, you have to pass data back-and-forth

Comment: @Guarav Arora How to update the list ? Do I need to write the code only inside the startActivityForResult() ? Can you please edit the code and given to me. I added the startActivityForResult() etc. But not able to update the list.

Comment: Please update your latest code and I can help editing it further.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use startActivityForResult() when starting the 'details' activity.

Check out the answer here which explains with more details: [How to manage `startActivityForResult` on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/android-how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result)